# @Api annotation of swagger is not generating the resourcePath for endpoints

Tags: python, swagger

I am trying to create python client using swagger documentation. But resourcePath is "/" so, `swagger-codegen-cli` is not creating pyhton client. Why is resourcePath empty ? How can it be fixed ? Thanks in advance..

```
{
  "apiVersion": "1.0",
  "swaggerVersion": "1.2",
  "basePath": "/",
  "resourcePath": "/",
```

Comment: If you can share more of the spec, this can probably be figured out pretty easily.  My guess is that because it's an older swagger version (1.2), the spec has something invalid in it.

Comment: Thanks..updating swagger to the latest version!